# How to store a string from a text file in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to read a text file into a string array and be able to access the array contents through a loop. The code I have allows me to store only the last line of the text file instead of the entire file; where am I going wrong?

```
#define MAX 10000

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[MAX];
    char *x[MAX];
    int i =0;
    char y[MAX];

    if((fp = fopen("550.txt", "r"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    exit(1);}

    while(!feof(fp)) {
        while(fgets(str, sizeof str, fp)) {
            x[i]= str;
            printf("%s", str);
            printf("%s", *(x+i));
            i++;
        }
  }


for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    printf("%s", *(x+i));
}

   fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use feof() to control loop cond.http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html

Answer (score 3):

You only allocate *one* string array `str`. At each iteration through the loop you are simply overwriting `str`. The assignment `x[i] = str` assigns the *pointer* value of `str` to `x[i]`. You'll notice that each member of the array `x` points to the *same* buffer `str` at the end of the loop. You need to create multiple buffers.

One way to do this is to define the maximum number of lines using `#define LINES 100` and then to declare `x` as follows

```
char x[LINES][MAX];
```

and then perform a `strcpy` at each iteration:

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof str, fp)) {
    strcpy(x[i], str);
    printf("%s", str);
    printf("%s", *(x+i));
    i++;
}
```

Note that you should consider using the `strncpy` method instead of `strcpy` and check the return value to ensure that the buffers do not overrun.

Comment: Are you sure that fgets will not zero-terminate the buffer for long input?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a copy of each string:

```
x[i] = strdup(str);
```

What you're doing at the moment is making each `x[i]` point to the same buffer, which will contain the last line of the file once you've finished.

(Note: you'll also need to `free()` all of the `x[i]` strings you create with `strdup()`.)

Answer (score 0):

you are not stroing the line you read anywhere. It is buffered into str but the you overwrite it with the next line. use strdup.

```
x[i] = strdup(str);
```